# Shadow not showing when background color is clear color

Tags: ios, calayer

I've created an uiview in my xib with background color as clear color. When I apply the shadow on the layer of the view, the shadow is not appearing. But when i set the background color other than clear color, shadow is showing. Please help.

this is my code

```
self.cView.layer.shadowColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.cView.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeZero;
self.cView.layer.shadowRadius=30.0;
self.cView.layer.shadowOpacity=1.0;
self.cView.layer.cornerRadius=10.0;
```

Comment: The answer is simply that you **have to set .shadowPath in layoutSubviews**.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is, that shadow actually takes into account the 'upper' layer. If there's nothing on it there will be no shadow: [How Shadows Work](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH208-SW1)

EDIT:

There is this recipe [copied from paste bin](http://pastebin.com/gzB1uWgQ)

```
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:.5 alpha:1].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
view.layer.shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), NULL);
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
```

But I doubt this will be of any use to you: the result is a view 'painted' with color of a shadow and a shadow around it.

Comment: Yes, shadows only occur when the view is opaque or there is some content in it. Setting clear color is like setting the view transparent.

Comment: The down side is, UIView.animate does not work with shadowPath.

Comment: @JamesL , it works perfectly.  Ignore this incorrect answer and see the code by Demosthese

Answer (score 18):

If you specify shadowPath property

```
shadowView.layer.shadowPath =
  UIBezierPath(
   roundedRect: shadowView.bounds,
   cornerRadius: 10).cgPath
```

(Or whatever corner radius is desired.)

it will work even with .clear backgroundColor.

Note that you of course have to do this in `layoutSubviews` of the view in question.

Here's an actual full working example:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class LonelyShadow: UIView {

    let corner: CGFloat = 20

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        common()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        common()
    }

    private func common() {

        backgroundColor = .clear
        clipsToBounds = false

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yourColor.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 25)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        layer.shadowRadius = 40
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(
          roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: corner).cgPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent to @Rok Jark's answer in Swift 4:

```
self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 1).cgColor
self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
self.layer.shadowPath = CGPath.init(rect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50), transform: nil)
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```

Comment: what if you don't know frame at the time of this initialization? @Demosthese above wrote absolutely correct example with layout sibviews