# UITableViewCell: rounded corners and shadow

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm changing the width of a UITableViewCell so that the cell is smaller but the user can still scroll along the edges of the tableview.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {        
    // Set the width of the cell
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width - 40, self.bounds.size.height)
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Then I round the corners:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

All good so far. Problem happens with the shadow. The bounds are masked, so the shadow obviously won't show up. I've looked up other answers but can't seem to figure out how to round the corners along the bounds *and* show the shadow.

```
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.23
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4
```

So my question – how do I reduce the width, round the corners, and add a shadow to a UITableViewCell at the same time?

**Update:** Trying R Moyer's answer

[image: Trying R Moyer's answer]

Comment: Do you need `masksToBounds` enabled? You might be able to adjust constraints to just not use that. Otherwise, what if you just make the cell's background clear and add another `UIView` inside of the cell that contains all of the cell's views. Then you can make that container view smaller with rounded corners and a shadow, without having to worry about the shadow being clipped.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This question comes at a good time! I literally JUST solved this same issue myself.

1. Create a `UIView` (let's refer to it as `mainBackground`) inside your cell's Content View. This will contain all of your cell's content. Position it and apply necessary constraints in the Storyboard.
2. Create another `UIView`. This one will be the one with the shadow (let's refer to it as `shadowLayer`). Position it exactly as you did `mainBackground`, but behind it, and apply the same constraints.
3. Now you should be able to set the rounded corners and the shadows as follows:

   ```
   cell.mainBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 8  
   cell.mainBackground.layer.masksToBounds = true

   cell.shadowLayer.layer.masksToBounds = false
   cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
   cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
   cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.23
   cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowRadius = 4
   ```

However, the problem here is: calculating the shadow for every single cell is a slow task. You'll notice some serious lag when you scroll through your table. The best way to fix this is to define a `UIBezierPath` for the shadow, then rasterize it. So you may want to do this:

```
cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.shadowLayer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .AllCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8)).CGPath
cell.shadowLayer.layer.shouldRasterize = true
cell.shadowLayer.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

But this creates a new problem! The shape of the `UIBezierPath` depends on `shadowLayer`'s bounds, but the bounds are not properly set by the time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. So, you need to adjust the `shadowPath` based on `shadowLayer`'s bounds. The best way to do this is to subclass `UIView`, and add a property observer to the bounds property. Then set all the properties for the shadow in `didSet`. Remember to change the class of your `shadowLayer` in the storyboard to match your new subclass.

```
class ShadowView: UIView {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            setupShadow()
        }
    }

    private func setupShadow() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8)).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

Comment: I setup the views and applied the constraints, but that didn't work. Corners are still square and no shadow is being applied. Thought it might be because both views have no color, made the necessary adjustments but no dice.

Comment: Are your views possibly hiding behind the cell's content view? Could you post a screenshot of your storyboard and/or the code from your UITableViewController?

Comment: Nope, they're ahead of the Content View in Storyboard. Also confirmed by debugging the view hierarchy while running the app. I connected the outlets to my cell subclass, and then I used your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Currently tinkering with it.

Comment: The only code I provided that should belong in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are the adjustments to the `mainBackground` view (rounded corners, mask to bounds). The code dealing with the `shadowLayer` should be in it's own subclass of UIView

Comment: Gotcha. But even with this setup, shouldn't the effects be applied? The shadow would just lag. Obviously not ideal (+ fixable with your solution), but the effects should still be applied nonetheless?

Comment: Yes, the effects should still be applied. But if you try to set the `shadowPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it won't be rendered properly on initial load.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll test it with `shadowLayer` in it's own subclass. Thanks.

Comment: I've uploaded some code to github for you to look at. The custom cells include rounded corners and shadows. https://github.com/moyerr/CandySearch-Custom-UITableViewCell

Comment: Setup the two views, connected them to my cell subclass. Added the Shadow View subclass. Used the same styling code you used. But no dice. Put a breakpoint on Shadow View class and it isn't being called. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you change the class of the shadowView in the Storyboard? When you connect the outlet to your cell class, the type of the shadowView should be `ShadowView!`

Comment: After setting ShadowView in Storyboard and adjusting the background colors of the cell and contentView (to `clearColor`), this is what I get: (see update to question for pic). Corner radius working but there's something underneath (I'm guessing the shadow). The shadow isn't displaying as it should.

Comment: See if you can get it working without messing with the colors first. Don't forget to round the corners of your `shadowView` too. It seems that shadows will not appear if the associated view is `clearColor`.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12928417

Comment: Worked once I adjusted shadowView and mainBackground to be smaller than the cell itself. Thanks.

Comment: wow! isn't there seriously an easier approach to round the corners and create a shadow for a collection view cell?

Comment: I would suggest to add to this answer: uncheck clipToBounds for Cell in Interface Builder ;)

Comment: tried that but not succeeded. also read all the comments. But the sample code give in this [gist](https://github.com/moyerr/CandySearch-Custom-UITableViewCell) works fine. Can't figure out the difference

Answer (score 63):

The accepted answer works but adding an extra subview to get this effect make little to no sense. Here is the solution that works.

**1st step**: Add shadow and corner radius

```swift
// do this in one of the init methods
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // add shadow on cell
    backgroundColor = .clear // very important
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.23
    layer.shadowRadius = 4
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    // add corner radius on `contentView`
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
}
```

**2nd step**: Mask to bounds in `willDisplay`

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // this will turn on `masksToBounds` just before showing the cell
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

**Bonus**: Smooth scrolling

```swift
// if you do not set `shadowPath` you'll notice laggy scrolling
// add this in `willDisplay` method
let radius = cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius
cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much more clean than adding a separate UIView for shadow. Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked for me after setting the tableviews clipsToBounds = false

Comment: Setting `masksToBounds` in `willDisplay` did it for me, thank you!

Comment: Did not work for me. The bounds of the view remain messed up. Guess this isn't the right way.

Comment: For me it worked when I put all properties inside awakeFromNib() function instead of init()

Comment: Not working at all

Answer (score 28):

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: in cellForItemAt indexPath

Answer (score 18):

To create shadow and corner for cell you need only one backView. See my example below.

[image]

You have to add `backView` and set `leading`, `trailing`, `top`, `bottom` constraints equal to `Content view`.
Put you content to `backView` with appropriate constraints, but be sure **your content not over cove**r `backView`.

After that in your cell initialisation code add these lines:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    backgroundColor = Colors.colorClear

    self.backView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    self.backView.layer.borderColor = Colors.colorClear.cgColor
    self.backView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.18
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    self.layer.shadowColor = Colors.colorBlack.cgColor
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Don't forget to create IBOutlet for `Back View`.

And here the result:

[image]

Comment: it worked but it show shadow on all 4 corners of view. How to add drop shadow only?

Comment: It's not working for me.Shadow is showing on the bottom of the cell only.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 8):

I have achieved the same thing using following code.But you have place it in layoutSubviews() method of your TableViewCell subclass.

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
self.contentView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;
CGRect shadowFrame = self.contentView.layer.bounds;
CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame].CGPath;
self.contentView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
```

Comment: in your custom cell view, call it in method layoutSubviews()

Comment: I have a containerView within contentView but still shadow not rendering in layoutSubview method within cell class.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative approach you can try, take a `UIView` in `UITableViewCell`. Set background color of `UITableViewCell` to clear color. Now, you can make round corners and add shadow on `UIVIew`. This will appear as if cell width is reduced and user can scroll along the edges of the tableView.

Comment: Currently testing this out.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 4):

create a UIVIEW inside cell's content view "backView"
and add an outlet of backView to cell class
then add these lines of code to awakeFromNib()

```
self.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 28
self.backView.clipsToBounds = true
```

the corner radius depends on your design...
the add these code to cellForRowAt function

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
```

and set the cell view background color to clear color

***Don't forget to add a little space between 4 sides of the cell and the backView you just added inside cell contentView in StoryBoard***

hope you liked it

Answer (score 4):

Regarding  answer [R Moyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6423848/r-moyer), the solution is excellent, but the bounds are not always installed after the cellForRowAt method, so as a possible refinement of his solution, it is to transfer the call of the setupShadow() method to the LayoutSubview() for example:

```
class ShadowView: UIView {

    var setupShadowDone: Bool = false
    
    public func setupShadow() {
        if setupShadowDone { return }
        print("Setup shadow!")
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, 
byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 
8)).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    
        setupShadowDone = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("Layout subviews!")
        setupShadow()
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it may be done much simplier with lazy var variable

Answer (score 4):

Let's Assume

- **viewContents** = its the view which contain all your views
- **viewContainer** = Its the view which contains **viewContents** with leading, trailing, top, bottom all are equal to zero.

Now the idea is, we are adding the shadow to the **viewContainer**. And rounding the corners of the **viewContents**. Most important don't forget to set background color of **viewContainer** to nil.

Here's the code snippet.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //viewContainer is the parent of viewContents
    //viewContents contains all the UI which you want to show actually.
    
    self.viewContents.layer.cornerRadius = 12.69
    self.viewContents.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.viewContainer.bounds, cornerRadius: 12.69)
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowPath = bezierPath.cgPath
    self.viewContainer.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 3)
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    
    // sending viewContainer color to the viewContents.
    let backgroundCGColor = self.viewContainer.backgroundColor?.cgColor
    //You can set your color directly if you want by using below two lines. In my case I'm copying the color.
    self.viewContainer.backgroundColor = nil
    self.viewContents.layer.backgroundColor =  backgroundCGColor
  }
```

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: are u using one cell in each section ?

Comment: @SultanAli Yes, I'm returning one row for each section.

Answer (score 2):

Never use UIBezierPath , bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame etc as its really heavy and draws a layer on top of the views and would require to reload the table view again to make sure the cells are rendering in the right way and sometimes even reloading might not help. Instead use a section header and footer which has rounded edges as required and also which is inside the storyboard which will make the scrolling and loading of table view very smooth without any rendering issues ( sometimes called missing cells and appears on scroll )

refer here how to set the different integer values for rounded corners here : [Setting masked corners in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699095/setting-masked-corners-in-interface-builder)

Just use the above values for your section header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

1- Create Custom TableViewCell Class 
. Paste the following code at class level right where you create IBOutlets. exerciseView is the view just inside ContentView to which you want to round.

```
@IBOutlet weak var exerciseView: UIView! {
        didSet {
            self.exerciseView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            self.exerciseView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
```

didSet is variable observer basically. You can do this in awakeFromNib function as well as:

```
self.exerciseView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
self.exerciseView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5


    let border = CALayer()
    let width = CGFloat(2.0)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cell.contentView.frame.size.height - width, width:  cell.contentView.frame.size.width, height: cell.contentView.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    cell.contentView.layer.addSublayer(border)
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Dude! its just a border :|

Answer (score 0):

It works without additional views!

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    let layer = cell.layer
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    layer.frame = cell.frame
    cell.tagLabel.text = tagItems[indexPath.row].text

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It gave me shadow but my cell's circle change pls check screen shot 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oy5ec9hee2krz0s/Screen%20Shot%202018-02-16%20at%202.15.35%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: and I want this effect 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809557/how-to-do-shadow-effect-in-collection-view-and-table-view-cell?noredirect=1#comment84625789_48809557

Answer (score 0):

```
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0.25
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's useful, I have been using the code below to achieve this, which only needs to be run in cellForRowAt.

First, add an extension to UITableViewCell to enable you to create a shadow and rounded corners on a TableViewCell:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func addShadow(backgroundColor: UIColor = .white, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 12, shadowRadius: CGFloat = 5, shadowOpacity: Float = 0.1, shadowPathInset: (dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat), shadowPathOffset: (dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat)) {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: shadowPathInset.dx, dy: shadowPathInset.dy).offsetBy(dx: shadowPathOffset.dx, dy: shadowPathOffset.dy), byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius)).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        
        let whiteBackgroundView = UIView()
        whiteBackgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        whiteBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        whiteBackgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        whiteBackgroundView.clipsToBounds = false
        
        whiteBackgroundView.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: shadowPathInset.dx, dy: shadowPathInset.dy)
        insertSubview(whiteBackgroundView, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Then just reference this in cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass

    cell.addShadow(backgroundColor: .white, cornerRadius: 13, shadowRadius: 5, shadowOpacity: 0.1, shadowPathInset: (dx: 16, dy: 6), shadowPathOffset: (dx: 0, dy: 2))
 
    // Or if you are happy with the default values in your extension, just use this instead:
    // cell.addShadow()

    return cell
}
```

Here is the result for me:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Afgl.png)

Comment: add below line & remove your last line
self.contentView.addSubview(whiteBackgroundView)
        self.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteBackgroundView)

Comment: @ben it's not working for me

Comment: dequeueReusableCell may be called multiple times for the same cell. The question is how many cells you need to see multiple shadows you add

Answer (score -1):

Since iOS 13 you just need to use the style  "UITableViewStyleInsetGrouped".