# Setting masked corners in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder

What type of value is `[.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]`? Is it possible to set this parameter on a View in Interface Builder? I know how to set `layer.borderWidth`, `layer.borderUIColor` and `layer.cornerRadius` in the Identity Inspector, but I can't figure out the right Type and Value to use for masked corners.

Thanks!

Jake

---

Update: here are the integer values for each combination (in terms of which are rounded):

- **0:** no rounded corners
- **1:** top left
- **2:** top right
- **3:** top left & right (both top corners)
- **4:** bottom left
- **5:** top & bottom left (both left corners)
- **6:** top right & bottom left
- **7:** top left & right, bottom left (all corners except bottom right)
- **8:** bottom right
- **9:** top left, bottom right
- **10:** top & bottom right (both right corners)
- **11:** both top corners, bottom right (all corners except bottom left)
- **12:** bottom left & right (both bottom corners)
- **13:** bottom left & right, top left (all corners except top right)
- **14:** bottom left & right, top right (all corners except top left)
- **15:** all corners rounded

---

- Top left is in 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15
- Top right is in 2-3, 6-7, 10-11, 14-15
- Bottom left is in 4-7, 12-15
- Bottom right is in 8-15
- Both top corners are in 3, 7, 11, 15
- Both right corners are in 10-11, 14,15
- Both bottom corners are in 12-15
- Both left corners are in 5, 7, 13, 15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`maskedCorners` is a CACornerMask, which is an OptionSet, or bit mask. The raw value is an integer: in code, you can try printing the value of `someView.layer.maskedCorners.rawValue`, or setting it via `someView.layer.maskedCorners.setValue(3, forKey: "maskedCorners")`.

So you should be able to set the value of `layer.maskedCorners` to the integer 3 (or whatever you need) in Interface Builder, and I don't see why it would be unsafe to do this. Though it will be a pain to figure out what set of corners that integer value actually maps to if you forget.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand correctly, I can use a different integer value for whichever corner or set of corners I want to mask? So like 1 might equal top left, 2 is top right, and 5 might be top right and bottom right or something, and I just have to work out which is which?

Comment: Exactly. Each corner is a power of 2, so any combination of corners you need will be a unique integer. Easiest way to find out the exact value you need is to write a bit of code in a view controller that sets up the corner mask you need for some random view, and then print out the `someView.layer.maskedCorners.rawValue` value to see what integer that corresponds to.

Comment: Awesome, I'll do that. Thanks again!

Comment: Or actually, if you look at the CACornerMask documentation in Objective-C (*not* Swift), you can see the raw values for each mask: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cacornermask?language=objc

Answer (score 5):

I've just randomly bumped into this same "issue" and wrote another solution, using an extension (no subclassing) and visual toggles in IB for each corner (without setting / adding the bit flags manually).

Keep in mind that the default settings are On / `true` (so that "cornerRadius" affects all corners of the view). If you want to round all corners except one, just set that particular corner to `false`.

[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
public extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get { return layer.cornerRadius }
        set { layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
    }

    @IBInspectable var topLeft: Bool {
        get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMinXMinYCorner) }
        set {
            if newValue {
                layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMinXMinYCorner)
            } else {
                layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMinXMinYCorner)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var topRight: Bool {
        get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMaxXMinYCorner) }
        set {
            if newValue {
                layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMaxXMinYCorner)
            } else {
                layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMaxXMinYCorner)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bottomLeft: Bool {
        get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMinXMaxYCorner) }
        set {
            if newValue {
                layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMinXMaxYCorner)
            } else {
                layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMinXMaxYCorner)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bottomRight: Bool {
        get { return layer.maskedCorners.contains(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner) }
        set {
            if newValue {
                layer.maskedCorners.insert(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner)
            } else {
                layer.maskedCorners.remove(.layerMaxXMaxYCorner)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not check if it works, but you may try c:

(Don't forget to apply the mask to your view )

```
@IBDesignable
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Preprocessor macro, you won't be able 
    // to use code inside this "if" statement from your... code
    // Just use cornerMask property directly
    #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
    @IBInspectable
    var topLeft: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerMask()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var topRight: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerMask()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var bottomLeft: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerMask()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var bottomRight: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerMask()
        }
    }

    func updateCornerMask() {
        cornerMask = CACornerMask(
            TL: topLeft,
            TR: topRight,
            BL: bottomLeft,
            BR: bottomRight)
    }
    #endif

    var cornerMask: CACornerMask?
}

extension CACornerMask {
    init(TL: Bool = false, TR: Bool = false, BL: Bool = false, BR: Bool = false) {
        var value: UInt = 0
        if TL { value += 1 }
        if TR { value += 2 }
        if BL { value += 4 }
        if BR { value += 8 }

        self.init(rawValue: value)
    }
}

// And yeah maybe using UIView makes more sense
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm not too familiar with `@IBInspectable`, `@IBDesignable` and preprocessor macros, but I definitely like the neatness of the math in the extension! I will check this out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder I set these by selecting the object you want to transform at run time and in user defined runtime attribute the KeyPath is `layer.cornerRadius` or `layer.maskedCorners` and the Type is `Number` and add the raw value of the corner you want to change.

[image]