# UIView shadow not working with custom extension

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview, uikit

I am trying to add a shadow to my UIViews using a custom extension that I created for the UIView class. Here is the code for the extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func round(_ radius : CGFloat = 10) {
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    func addBorder(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
        layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = width
    }

    func addShadow(opacity: Float, size: Double, radius: Double, color: UIColor ) {
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

The round and addBorder functions work perfectly fine, but the addShadow function does not seem to be working. I have tried calling the function on a UIView instance like this:

```
let myView = UIView()
myView.addShadow(opacity: 0.5, size: 2, radius: 4, color: .black)
```

But the shadow does not show up on the view

I have tested this extension with other types of views, such as buttons and labels, and the shadow works perfectly fine. It seems to be a problem only with UIViews.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may be caused by the `layer.masksToBounds = true` line in the `addShadow` function. This property clips the sublayers of the layer to the layer's bounds, which could be preventing the shadow from being displayed.

You can try setting `masksToBounds` to false before adding the shadow to the layer.

Comment: If I make it false then whats about other views such as TableViewCell..?

Comment: @YasirArefinTusher What do you mean by "what about TableViewCell"? What are you asking about table view cells?

Comment: If I make this false then other views like TableViewCell  or Buttons shadow not shows.. But in this situation UIViews shadows are works well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YasirArefinTusher Well if you actually wanted to ask about `UITableViewCell`, *ask about that instead*. [It has been asked before though](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37645408/5133585).

Comment: @Sweeper Actually I was trying to add shadow using extensions. So that I don't write shadow code everywhere.

Comment: @YasirArefinTusher In that case. You should make layer.masksToBounds to false again after adding shadow. By that I mean,

yourXibCell.addShadow(opacity: 0.5, size: 2, radius: 4, color: .black)
yourXibCell.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: @Md.AsifNawaz do you asking to override masksToBounds in the tableviewCell?

Answer (score 3):

By setting `layer.masksToBounds = true`, you are telling the view's layer to clip any content that goes beyond its bounds, which would include the shadow you are trying to add.

```
func addShadow(opacity: Float, size: Double, radius: Double, color: UIColor ) {
layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
layer.shadowRadius = radius }
// remove this line: layer.masksToBounds = true
```

If that doesn't work, you might want to try changing the backgroundColor attribute of the view to a color that isn't translucent. If there is no content to render, the shadow won't be seen since shadows are produced by displaying the content of the layer.

Answer (score 2):

If we use clipsToBounds = true it will clip the frame and the shadow was cut off
just replace the line with clipsToBounds = false will fix it.
here is the modified code

```swift
extension UIView {
    extension UIView {
        func round(_ radious: CGFloat = 10) {
            layer.cornerRadius = radious
            clipsToBounds = false
        }

        func addBorder(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
            layer.borderWidth = width
        }

        func addShadow(opecity: Float, size: Double, radius: Double, color: UIColor ) {
            layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
            layer.shadowOpacity = opecity
            layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
            layer.shadowRadius = radius
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yasir I have the same difficulty with shadows. I have solved it with this extension. Try it.

```
extension UIView {
    /// show drop shadow under view
    /// - Parameter scale: bool variable to enable scaling
    func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 10
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1

    }
}
```

Comment: But this can’t be used along with rounded corners. Right?

Comment: I need to verify it @HangarRash
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

layer.masksToBounds should be false to disables the layer's mask to display the shadow outside of the view's bounds.

```
layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: If I disable this other functions such as addBorder not works correctly.

Comment: you can create a separate CALayer to serve as the border layer.

Comment: In my CustomView or In the Extension ?